# sql count where records in 2 tables almost match

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm at a loss to figure out how to write the SQL code to pull the count of rownames in table 1 that appear in table 2 where the rowumber is +/- 1. For example, I would count 'Exclusive' and 'Popular Episodes' as appearing in both because the rownumber is within 1 of each other. But I would NOT count 'Popular Movies', because the gap is > 1. Normally I would INTERSECT the tables, but I only know how to use INTERSECT for exact matches.

```
Table 1
+------------------+-----------+
|  rowname         | rownumber |
+------------------+-----------+
| Exclusive        |         1 |
| Popular Movies   |         3 |
| New Seasons      |         7 |
| Popular Episodes |         8 |
+------------------+-----------+

Table 2
+------------------+-----------+
|   rowname        | rownumber |
+------------------+-----------+
| Exclusive        |         2 |
| Popular Episodes |         7 |
| Popular Movies   |         8 |
+------------------+-----------+
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: How about if New Seasons is 1 in Table 1 and NULL (not existing) in Table 2, would that count?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not a simple join? Something like:

```
SELECT rowname
FROM t1 JOIN t2 ON t1.rowname = t2.rowname
WHERE t1.rownumber - t2.rownumber BETWEEN -1 AND 1
```

Just fix the names.

Or SELECT COUNT(rowname) if you just want the number.

Comment: How would this change if the rowname appears more than once in Table1 (ie it appears in row 1 and 12)?

Comment: That would make it a complete different question. If rownames are not unique, the question does not make sense (new logic would be needed).

Comment: I'm not sure I understand why this is a different question. If Popular Movies were in Table 1 in rownumber 3 AND rownumber 9, then I would want the solution to include Popular Movies instead of exclude it.

Comment: If there are multiple entries to be compared, it's mandatory to set how they would be compared - the AND / OR logic (at least one of them to match? all of them? in a particular order? to a limit? one count per rowname? multiple times?)

Answer (score 0):

If you will consider the blank record in either table to be 0 like for 'New Seasons' if it will be 1, you use LEFT JOIN instead.

```
SELECT t1.rowname
  FROM table1 t1
  LEFT JOIN table2 t2 
    ON t1.rowname = t2.rowname 
 WHERE COALESCE(t1.rownumber,0) - COALESCE(t2.rownumber,0) BETWEEN -1 AND 1
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll try these and let you know how it goes!

Comment: JOIN or INNER JOIN should not include it

Comment: I tested on a different dataset than my posted example. My mistake!